# Idea display Cannot resolve file "fmt"

Tags: go, intellij-idea

I am using Idea to develop the golang program, I have set the go root and go path. And I have added go plugin for the Idea. The Idea also warn that Cannot resolve file "fmt". But the program works normally.

```
package main

import "fmt"
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, World!")
}
```

[image]

I want the Idea give me the right message. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Which IDE version/go plugin version are you using? Have you tried setting the Go SDK via Settings | Go | GOROOT? Does the problem still exist?

Comment: IDE version: IU-172.3317.76
Go plugin version: v172.3317-EAP-CANDIDATE-SNAPSHOT.20
There are not Go  in the Settings. 
Yes, the problem still exist.

Comment: You need to use IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2017.3 or newer to be able to install the Go plugin supported by JetBrains. In IDEA you'll find the settings under Settings | Language & Frameworks | Go | GOROOT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which go-lang plugin are you using?

In any case, define a go SDK under platform settings. Make sure you include your local `GOPATH` under classpath.

Also see: https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/issues/1368

Comment: That plugin is not compatible with the current version of Intellij, btw.  They discontinued it in favor of the official one, which is unfortunately only available in the paid version of Intellij now.

Comment: After I upgrade the idea and go-lang plugin to 2018 version, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem and has solved it after downgrading golang version from 1.11 to 1.9.5.

I am using Idea2017.1.6 for community, and the go plugin came from [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/5047-go-language-golang-org-support-plugin), which is developed by google. As of now, only idea2017.1 and earlier version are compatible.

BTW, [go plugin developed by jetbrains](http://%20https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9568-go) is only available from ultimate version.